# Why did the War Boys give Max a haircut and shave?

Tags: plot-explanation, mad-max-fury-road

As the title asks, why did the War Boys in *Mad Max: Fury Road* cut Max's hair? There was a kid collecting the hair. Why?

Answer (score 3):

You bring in an almost feral person from outside, beyond cleaning up the stink, you don't want them passing lice, bedbugs and whatever other vermin might be nesting in the filth that is their hair.  Hygiene would be a practical reason for doing that.

Comment: Only reason that makes sense so far. +1. If you had some evidence instead of just logic, that would be perfect.

Answer (score 2):

i think the war pup collected the hair for the simple fact that he just wanted it, he had most likely never seen actual hair, considering the fact that he, and all the other war boys are bald.

Comment: True,  all the war boys we see are bald, but the Mechanic and Immortan Joe and others weren't. Evidence that this is what they intended would be nice.  But +1.

Answer (score 0):

They use the Hair to stitch up wounded War Boys, same explanation as to why the Organic Mechanic has patchy hair.

Comment: please elaborate your answer

Answer (score -2):

Maybe it's just their dress code, also if you observe closely they all had some white ash looking powder smeared on their head, so i think it's safe to concur that because the heat was too much a short or trim haircut is a better choice and also ash acts like a natural cooling substance, Maybe just maybe

Comment: Why did they shave and collect the hair from the Blood-Bag Max, not why they did it to themselves. They don't use the ash or anything for Max.

Comment: they wanted to convert him to war boy who have shaved head, dont know y the war pup was collecting hair

Comment: They did not want Max to be a war boy...

Comment: why do you think they captured him alive

Comment: To use as a blood bag to keep radiation poisoned war boys alive. That's obvious.

Comment: the body only produces a certain amount of blood, and even after giving blood the body needs certain set of nutrients to regain that lost blood ,hence i am sure in the long run if max had not fought he would be a war boy

Comment: The white ash was specifically to imitate Immortan Joe, who needs the white powder as medication for his sickness. So it's not about heat. http://www.thedailybeast.com/articles/2015/05/15/now-you-can-get-the-mad-max-look.html

Comment: @cde nice job bud,